# What is the spatial equivalent of chronological or chronology?

Tags: single-word-requests

[Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chronological) definition of **chronological**:

> of, relating to, or arranged in or according to the order of time

The *spatially equivalent* adjective I'm looking for would, ideally, be defined as:

> of, relating to, or arranged in or according to the order *in space*

[American Heritage's](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=chronology) definition of **chronology**:

> The arrangement of events in time.

The *spatial* noun would be defined as:

> The arrangement of *objects in space*.

I've considered **sequential** and **sequence**, respectively. I understand them to refer to order in general and not specifically to spatial or temporal order; either context seems appropriate.

Likewise for **serial** and **series**.

Comment: chronology, chronological/time, temporal/space,spacial. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Lambie Chronological means ordered in time. E.g., chronological events. What's an adjective for ordered in space? E.g., spatially sequential objects. I'm looking for an unambiguous single word.

Comment: I think you are going for a false analogy. spatially ordered objects. The ordering of objects in space and time is one thing. Chronology is another.

Comment: "Geometry" describes the relationships of objects in space, but I don't think it will work very well for your purposes. However, I doubt that there is a single word that will do the trick.

Comment: If you are wanting to describe physical arrangements, *layout* could probably be used.

Comment: Your own term “arrangement” works.

Comment: You're very unlikely to come across a word with all four subsenses (a) belonging to the order in space, (b) relating to the order in space, (c) arranged in [some] order in space and (d) according to [its] order in space [of objects, say]. Nonce compounds using 'arrangement' before a head noun (arrangement-oriented?) are a possibility. But if actual order needs to be referenced, I think 'sequencing' or 'order', though ballpark, are as close as it gets.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done in a single word, although *arrangement* comes close. Perhaps *spatial configuration*.

Comment: Time has a one-dimensional order, space does not. If you mean a word for a collection of symbolic objects arranged in a symbolic space to match the arrangement of the objects in the real world, that is a (spatial) model or a map. *Cartographic* or similar might apply to the latter. But this question needs more information about how you plan to use the word in order to be answerable.

Comment: *dimension, dimensionality* (t, x, y, z). Blame the *t* on Einstein. Or take it up with this guy here → https://www.quantamagazine.org/a-mathematicians-guided-tour-through-high-dimensions-20210913/ OR just use *spatial* b/c it's an array not an order. Stuff is just wherever the sun threw it or whatever; IDK.

Answer (score 3):

Although mostly used to describe elements in a computer network, one term to consider is ***topology***:

> **2** The way in which constituent parts are interrelated or arranged.
>   *‘the **topology** of a computer network’*
>   <sub>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/topology)</sub>

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work too well for ordering, but it does work for "arrangement".

Comment: @HotLicks: A "topological sort" is a partial ordering, but its usage is also kind of specialized.

Answer (score -1):

Seriation is, IMHO, what you seem to be describing,though I could be mistaken

[seriation](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/seriation#:%7E:text=(%CB%8Cs%C9%AA%C9%99r%C9%AA%CB%88e%C9%AA%CA%83%C9%99n%20),things%20in%20series%20or%20succession)

> NOUN the arrangement of a collection of artifacts into a chronological
> sequence

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).